# Super simple script runs on some pages, not others. Why?

Tags: javascript, safari, userscripts

I have a super simple script (running in a Userscript manager for Safari) that works on some pages but not all.

Here is the script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Close tab on double click
// @include        https://*
// ==/UserScript==

                                  
document.addEventListener("dblclick",function (event) {
    window.close();
            });
```

For some reason, it works on Stack Overflow, Reddit post pages, etc., but does NOT work on Reddit homepage, Google (homepage or search results), etc.

Why?

Thanks for any insight. I'm still a newbie about javascript.

Edit: Working now, using the GM.closeTab permission from my Userscript manager, as documented here: https://github.com/quoid/userscripts#api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a chrome browser, when I add the JS function in the console and then double click on the page I get this notification (I tried the stack overflow site):
[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRr6t.png)

My guess is your userscript manager may add the script you write differently depending on the website, and the websites that don't work are because of this warning. Try opening your console after you add the script and see if you get this warning when double clicking does not work.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't even think about checking the console (like I said, newbie). That took me down a rabbit hole. Apparently there is an issue using window.close(); where scripts cannot invoke it unless the tab was opened by the script, as a security measure. After playing around, I found that normal tabs do not close, but tabs opened from others (via ctrl-click) will close.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
// @grant        window.close
```

in order to use `window.close` per [the documentation](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:grant).

Comment: Doesn't work. There was thread about this issue at https://github.com/quoid/userscripts/issues/310 but though it seems marked as resolved, it's still not working for me. Not sure if anyone else is getting it to function correctly but I've pretty much given up trying.

Comment: Update: Working now. Needed the `@grant GM.closeTab` permission and call!